# a-fame - Error loading online DPDB

Tags: aframe, webvr

I've been getting this error while testing an a-frame project in safari mobile:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Error loading online DPDB!**

This error doesn't show up on desktop, just on mobile. It also causes the page to refresh which is not good at all.

I tried googling the error and I've only found this one page on github about it:
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2385

However, it doesn't look like anyone has a fix for it. I did a little digging in the console and it appears to be an issue with webvr-polyfill.js.

Anybody have an idea what could be going on?

Comment: Jordan Santell from Google just opened a PR to update the polyfill. Hopefully fixes things.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Also just an FYI I'm also getting a bunch of warnings about an invalid timestamp.  "Invalid timestamps detected. Time step between successive gyroscope sensor samples is very small or not monotonic" - "updateDeviceMotion_ — webvr-polyfill.js:6607"